# ERROR 1064 (42000): mysql 5.0.77 server : tablespace creation error

Tags: mysql, tablespace

Server version: 5.0.77 Source distribution

I am getting error while creation of tablespaces

```
CREATE TABLESPACE `ts1` ADD DATAFILE 'ts1.ibd' ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Error is

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TABLESPACE `ts1` ADD DATAFILE 'ts1.ibd' ENGINE=INNODB' at line 1'
```

I understand, There are two different types of quotation marks in MySQL (` for column names and ' for strings). Why i am getting above error?

Comment: Use quoting only when it is needed really. Shown name used as tablespace name does not need in quoting. PS. I cannot find "CREATE TABLESPACE" command in Reference Manual for MySQL 5.0.xx version.

Comment: @Akina ...After removing the quotes, still getting the same error.

Comment: Error message points you to the word "TABLESPACE". This means that this is a problem - i.e. your ancient MySQL version simply does not support CREATE TABLESPACE command.